# Write a function that throw repeatedly a dice until N sixes have been thrown

Tags: r

I have tried this but i know it only notifies me when I get one 6 but not N sixes but I have no idea what to write to get N sixes. Then in the exercise they ask  Write the main program that calls the function, say, 100 times for different values of N and plots the
average number of times the dice had to be thrown as a function of N.

```
two.dice1.1 <- function(){

  nthrows=1

  while ((sample(1:6, size =1 , replace = TRUE))<6) {

    nthrows=nthrows+1
  } 

  return(nthrows)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "N sixes"? What behaviour are you expecting?

Comment: how much throw do you need to do with one dice to get 2 sixes or 3 sixes and so on ,

Comment: why is the function called `two.dice` while you are sampling with `size =1` and `replace = TRUE` ? Is size supposed to be 2?  And don't  you need `N` as an input if you want to try something like 'how many throws would it take to draw N times of 6 (or sum of two dice equals 6)?' etc.

Comment: If you're rolling `size=1` di, why use `sum`?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to stochastically reproduce a binomial distribution, brute-force. If you need the effect and don't need to do it by hand, perhaps the `?rbinom` binomial distribution functions will be useful.

Comment: @KM_83 I have call my function two dice for no particular reason and no it's not supposed to be 2 and the sum was a mistake and yes maybe I need N as a input but im not sure how to do that.

Comment: I will just add now  the second question of the exercise maybe I will help to understund my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could use a function like this:

```
  throw.dice <- function(target.number=NULL, target.successes=NULL){
  stopifnot(!is.null(target.number), !is.null(target.successes))
  
  ntrows <- 0
  score <- 0
  while(score < target.successes){
    n <- sample(1:6, 1)
    if(n == target.number){
      score <- score + 1
    }
    ntrows <- ntrows + 1
  }
  return(list(number.of.throws = ntrows, target.successes= target.successes, target.number = target.number))
}

mean.case <- data.frame()
for(n in 1:50){
  case <- NULL
  
  for(i in 1:100){
    throw <- throw.dice(6, n)$number.of.throws
    
    case[i] <- (throw)
    
  }
  mean.case <- rbind(mean.case, cbind(target.successes = n, 
                                      meantrhows = mean(case))) 
}

barplot(mean.case$meantrhows, 1, names.arg = mean.case$target.successes)
```

I have edited the answer to fulfill the final section of your problem! What I've done is a simple loop for repeating 100 times for each target success and then plot it.

Comment: Thank you I will try

Comment: This work without any problems thank you , now I will try to plot that.

Comment: Excellent! I've edited the answer to better suit your problem. Check it out.

Comment: Thank you very much you! Really help me